# OpenSSL: can one stop hashing a large file, and resume later?

Tags: node.js, hash, openssl, cryptography

I am dealing with very large (100GB+) video files stored across distributed systems. These files need to be hashed, but often it's not efficient to calculate the hash of a file on one computer in one operation.

Is there a way, using OpenSSL, to:

- stop a hash operation part-way through a file
- output the internal state of the hash algorithm
- store that internal state
- later resume the hashing operation from where it left off, by injecting the internal state back in, and continuing from the point in the file where original hash operation stopped?

Various different use cases:

1. A file's parts are distributed across multiple computers and no one computer has the whole file.
2. A file is present (in full) on multiple different computers. Spread load by performing the first part of a hash on system A, then complete it on system B.
3. In case of a network error or system crash, be able to resume a hashing operation from where it left off, rather than start again from the beginning.

There are various hash algorithms I need to use: MD5, SHA1, SHA256.

NB Dividing a file into blocks and hashing each block independently is not an option, as often the hash needs to validated against e.g. a known MD5 value for the whole file.

From my understanding of the working of hash functions, this seems to me to be theoretically feasible, but I can't work out from the docs whether it's possible with OpenSSL (command line).

If OpenSSL cannot do this, I would be interested in other solutions, particularly ones using Node.js.

Any help would be hugely appreciated.

Comment: See [EVP_Digest functions](https://www.openssl.org/docs/manmaster/man3/EVP_DigestInit.html). You are interested particularly in the `EVP_MD_CTX_copy` functions.

Comment: Thanks very much @JamesKPolk. But I did not explain myself well - sorry. I meant using the openssl command line executable.

Comment: Questions about general computing hardware and software are off-topic for Stack Overflow unless they directly involve tools used primarily for programming. You may be able to get help on Super User.

Comment: @JamesKPolk Interesting question anyway. Do you know how much state is kept when using `EVP_MD_CTX_copy`? Do you need it at the end of a hash block or is some input kept as well? Is the intermediate state of the partial hash in a specific, well defined format? Internal knowledge about Merkle-Damgard hashes required to understand this comment.

Comment: Technically this is possible, but certainly not with the command line. Hashing with a Merkle Damgard hash (and SHA3) is performed one block at a time, but at the end a block containing padding and length (of the message) is used. As no intermediate hashes are available using the command line this will not work.

Comment: @MaartenBodewes: I've never used it but I assume it saves any internally buffered input less than a complete hash block. It appears the state is in an internal format only intended to be supplied to other EVP_Digest functions in openssl.

Comment: MD5 and to a lesser extend SHA-1 should not be used anymore to calculate hashes over files as both have been broken with regards to collision resistance.